# jQuery getting each parent index returns incorrect numbers

Tags: jquery

If I for example create an event when $(this) is clicked than get the position of each parent element. For some reason my code returns an incorrect index at its $(this[0]).nodeName I sometimes get a index that is 1, 2 or 3 which is incorrect. And sometimes the .parents(selector).index() also is wrong.

I do get the correct index on the one that is correct, but also get incorrect values from parents or children that are of the one that is correct wrong.

As you can see i had to skip anything with an id and the body from returning an index value of more than 0, which i still don't understand why. I guess the .index() can't hold element+id

So clearly i'm doing something wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

The code that I created is a rebuild from other snippets of code I found.

IFRAME

```
<iframe class="feedgo-iframe" id="feedgo" frameborder="0" border="0" src="/dashboard/temp_iframe/20141211153854-rXHSMeHV7R.html"></iframe>
```

The code below is part of the html code, the full code with all its parents are loaded inside an iframe.

HTML which holds two articles (partial code) into the iframe on the same domain

```
   <html>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <article class="sw-home-articles">
            <div class="sw-head">
               <p>Article1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
               <i class="glyphicons-icon notes"></i>
               <h2><a href="http://example.com">my title</a></h2>
            </div>
            <p>my description</p>
            <div class="sw-category">
               posted in: <a href="http://www.example.com/article/tutorials/seo/" title="View all posts in SEO">SEO</a> <a href="http://www.example.com/article/tutorials/" title="View all posts in Tutorials">Tutorials</a> <a href="http://www.example.com/article/tutorials/wordpress/" title="View all posts in WordPress">WordPress</a>
               <p>Date posted: 17 August, 2014</p>
            </div>
         </article>
         <article class="sw-home-articles">
            <div class="sw-head">
               <p>Article2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
               <i class="glyphicons-icon notes"></i>
               <h2><a href="http://example.com">my title</a></h2>
            </div>
            <p>my description</p>
            <div class="sw-category">
               posted in: <a href="http://www.example.com/article/tutorials/seo/" title="View all posts in SEO">SEO</a> <a href="http://www.example.com/article/tutorials/" title="View all posts in Tutorials">Tutorials</a> <a href="http://www.example.com/article/tutorials/wordpress/" title="View all posts in WordPress">WordPress</a>
               <p>Date posted: 17 August, 2014</p>
            </div>
         </article>
      </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

jQuery

```
$("#feedgo").contents().find("*").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    $.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

    var $el = $(this);

    var reverse_parents = $el.parents().reverse();
    var selectors = "";

    $.each(reverse_parents, function(key, value) {
        var tag_name = $(value).prop("tagName").toLowerCase();
        var class_name = $(value).attr("class");
        var id_name = $(value).attr("id");
        var getindex = "";

        selectors += tag_name;
        getindex += tag_name;

        if (id_name !== undefined) {
            selectors += "#" + id_name;
        } else if (class_name !== undefined) {
            selectors += "." + $.trim(class_name).replace(/\s/gi, ".");
            getindex += "." + $.trim(class_name).replace(/\s/gi, ".");
        }

        if (id_name !== undefined) {
            var skip_index_search = 1;
        } else if (tag_name == "body") {
            var skip_index_search = 1;
        } else {
            var skip_index_search = 0;
        }

        if (skip_index_search == 0) {
            var eachindex = $el.parents(getindex).index();
        }

        if (eachindex >= 1) {
            selectors += ":nth-child(" + eachindex + ")";
        }

        selectors += " ";

    });


    selectors += $el[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
    //var getindex = $el[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();

    //var test = $(this).parent().find(getindex).index(this);


    var index = $($el).index();
    if (index) {
        index = index + 1;
        if (index >= 1) {
            selectors += ":nth-child(" + index + ")";
        }
    }


    console.log(selectors);


});
```

Required output example 1

```
"html body div.container div#main div.sw-content-wrap div.sw-content div.sw-block-1 div.sw-inner-block article.sw-home-articles:nth-child(1) p"
```

Require output example 2

```
"html body div.container div#main div.sw-content-wrap div.sw-content div.sw-block-1 div.sw-inner-block article.sw-home-articles:nth-child(3) div.clearfix h2 a"
```

Incorrect output example 2

```
"html body div.container div#main div.sw-content-wrap div.sw-content div.sw-block-1 div.sw-inner-block article.sw-home-articles:nth-child(3) div.clearfix:nth-child(1) h2:nth-child(1) a"
```

Comment: It would be more clear if you post the html, required output.

Comment: Thanks Amit Joki that is indeed more helpful

Comment: Where is id=feedgo in your html?

Comment: Hi @briansol I have updated it to be more clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found from a previous answer, I lost the link sorry. And that I had to select the child and not the descendant.

Here is the rewritten jQuery combined with the other solution.

```
    $("#feedgo").contents().find("*").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    $.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

    var mouse_get   = $('#mouse-tail').data("get");

    var $el = $(this);

        var selectors = $($el).parents().andSelf().map(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tagName = this.nodeName;
        var path = this.nodeName.toLowerCase();

        var class_name  = $this.attr("class");

        if ($this.attr("class") !== undefined){
            tagName += "."+$.trim(class_name).replace(/\s/gi, ".");
        }

        if ($this.siblings(tagName).length > 0) {
            var index = $this.prevAll(tagName).length +1;
            tagName += ":nth-child(" + index + ")";
        }
        return tagName;

    }).get().join(" > ");

    var content = $('#feedgo').contents().find(selectors);

    });
```